# How to send/check the status of an IDoc sent to SAP ECC through ALE Audit?

Tags: sap-erp, idoc, sapjco3

I am working on a Java application that receives Intermediate Documents (IDocs) from ECC and passes IDocs to ECC.

Our application works like a bridge between ECC and other systems, it receives IDocs from ECC that are stored in disk by our application, then a background process is in charge of checking the file system location where the files with the IDocs are saved and later sent to other destinations through HTTP requests. The application also communicates with these other systems to retrieve information that is also saved to files, and then on a background process, to read them and construct IDocs to be sent to ECC.

When the application receives an IDoc from ECC, it sends a confirmation IDoc to ECC, something similar needs to be done when sending to ECC, that is, when the Java application sends IDocs to it, we want ECC to send an ALE confirmation to our application if the IDocs were sent correctly, so our application knows the batch that was sent can be moved to our history folder safely, and in case the confirmation indicates there was a problem, another attempt to send the IDocs should be made.

How can we configure ECC to send a confirmation to our Java application?

To listen to incoming IDocs we use a private library but it also uses the JCo IDoc library.

Can the JCo IDoc library be used to check on the status of an IDoc sent? Or is there a way to configure ECC to send confirmations of every IDoc it has received?

The code we use to send from Java to ECC is this:

```java
try {
     destination= JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(PROGID);
     iDocRepository = JCoIDoc.getIDocRepository(destination);
     tid = destination.createTID();
     iDocFactory = JCoIDoc.getIDocFactory();
 } catch (JCoException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 List<Invoic02> invoic02s = new ArrayList<>();

 EDI_DC40 edi_dc40 = IdocUtil.generateIdocControlRecordObject(IdocUtil.invoiceIdocType, IdocUtil.invoiceMsgType);

 for(InvoiceIdoc invoicIdoc : invoices){
     Invoic02 invoic02 = new Invoic02();
     invoicIdoc.setBEGIN("1");
     invoicIdoc.setEDI_DC40(edi_dc40);
     invoic02.getInvoiceIdoc().add(invoicIdoc);
 }

 String invoicesIdocString = XmlParser.objectToXmlString(invoices, Invoic02.class);

 try {
     IDocXMLProcessor processor= iDocFactory.getIDocXMLProcessor();
     IDocDocumentList iDocList=processor.parse(iDocRepository, invoicesIdocString.toString());
     JCoIDoc.send(iDocList, IDocFactory.IDOC_VERSION_DEFAULT, destination, tid);
 } catch (JCoException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IDocParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard IDOC input methods (http and function), it is return IDOC save number. So you don't need waiting another IDOC. Just checking IDOC save number in response.

Comment: The IDOCs are being sent from ECC through ALE, from the Java application we use the JCO IDOC library, check the code in my updated question

Comment: what we want is for ECC to send an ALE confirmation to our application or to know if the JCO IDOC library is capable of checking the status of IDOCs sent to ECC

Comment: You can check your IDOC successfully saved by ECC with destination.confirmTID(tid) command. I understand that you need IDOC successfully processed or not. There are a lot of reason for your IDOC fail while it will processing. I think you need call RFC function GET_STATUS_FROM_IDOCNR with SAP java library or web service.

Comment: confirmTID seems to only throw an exception is the confirmation operation fails, but if the idoc is received successfully but it's status is error that method wouldn't notify me of such status

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, checking **TID** is the only way on Java-side to be sure your IDoc was received successfully. SAP [best practice](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/5df98bfb2451eee10000000a421937/content.htm) gives us no either ways:

> tid = destination.createTID();
>   ...
>   JCoIDoc.send(iDocList, IDocFactory.IDOC_VERSION_DEFAULT, destination, tid);
>   **destination.confirmTID(tid);**
>
>   return true;

This line [throws errors](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/javadoc/com/sap/conn/jco/JCoDestination.html#confirmTID(java.lang.String)) if something was wrong on the ERP-side.

Comment: From what I read on the confirmTID method specification, an exception is thrown is something failed while performing the confirmation, if the status of the idoc is error an exception wouldn't be thrown if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Yes, you are right. It can check only if it was received. The erroneous processing status of IDoc (`STATUS` field in `EDIDC`) technically doesn't mean something went wrong with the delivery of IDoc. It tells us that some logical error occured in IDoc inbound FM.

Comment: And that is what my question is about, I want some way to know about the status of any IDocs the application sends to ERP, it seems making a custom RFC is one of the ways but we want to avoid that instead to relay in ERP configuration to sent some confirmation on the status of the IDoc it received.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your comment under Suncatcher answer, you want to query the status of the IDoc after it has been processed at ECC side.

First, you are using transactional RFC, so the processing at ECC side is asynchronous, so you have to wait an undefined time until the IDoc is processed by SAP.

Consequently, you have two possibilities:

- Either your application regularly queries the status of IDocs at ECC side
- Or you schedule the program **`RBDSTATE`** at ECC side, as a background job triggered at regular intervals, which sends confirmations for processed IDocs, and you develop an additional java application which listens to these confirmations. I suggest that you choose the RFC protocol to send the confirmations.

  - `RBDSTATE` scans the processed IDocs and sends a confirmation IDoc of type **`ALEAUD01`** to the sender system, which contains the numbers of the IDoc processed, their processing status (success, error), messages, business objects created or changed...
  - You have to configure the partner profiles, port, connection data (transaction codes `WE20`, `WE21`, `BD97`, `SM59`)
  - You have to develop a new java application which operates as an RFC server, which listens to anything which arrives, and which processes inbound `ALEAUD01` IDocs.
  - You may obtain more information in the [SAP Library about ALE Audit](https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q=%22Monitoring+the+Status+of+Inbound+IDocs+Using+ALE+Audit%22&language=en-US&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_750).
  - Concerning the development of the RFC server application in java, you may obtain more information in the [SAP Library about SAP JCO Server Programming](https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q=%22SAP+JCo+Server+Programming%22&language=en-US&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_750).